# How to resolve the Vuetify error "installComponents has already been declared"?

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js latest version throws the following error while building or deploying the project that has Vuetify.

remote: > import installComponents from "!../node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/runtime/installComponents.js"

```
   Module parse failed: Identifier 'installComponents' has already been declared (53:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| /* vuetify-loader */
> import installComponents from "!../../../node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/runtime/installComponents.js"
| import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib'
| import { VCard } from 'vuetify/lib'
```

Comment: Please share your **nuxt.config.js** file content

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without a nuxt.config.js. But I had a problem like that. Earlier, I used a plugin to connect Vuetify. Then I installed the @nuxtjs/vuetify module, and the problem came up.

The problem is most likely related to treeShaking. @nuxtjs/vuetify turns on treeShaking only when the build happens. So you don't have a problem in dev mode, but there are problems with the build.

In my case the reason was that I forgot to remove VuetifyLoaderPlugin from the build section in nuxt.config.js.

```
transpile: ['vuetify/lib'],
plugins: [new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()],
```

Also I recommend enable treeShaking for the dev mode too. This will allow to use SASS variables in dev-mode. From @nuxtjs/vuetify version 2 it will always be enabled.

```
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'], // need treeShake
    treeShake: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove buildModules inside nuxt.config.js, this is for those who are using Nuxt.js

```
{
  buildModules: [
    // Simple usage
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',

    // With options
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { /* module options */ }]
  ]
}
```

Add modules this one is for latest version

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],
vuetify: {
//what ever options you may like
  },
```